# Smooth scroll inside absolute container?

Tags: jquery, scroll

I'm trying to target anchors inside a div using a smooth scroll script. The issue is that the links aren't targeting the correct anchor points. I have it sort of working. Thoughts?

**Fiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/YtJcL/691/

I'm basically using this script:

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('#wrapper').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: A more specific question might get a more specific answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer:

**Updated Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/YtJcL/694/

**Reference:** [Smooth scrolling within element, only first link/anchor works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23305033/smooth-scrolling-within-element-only-first-link-anchor-works?rq=1)

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('#wrapper').animate({
          scrollTop: $('#wrapper').scrollTop() + target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```